# How to simplify $\left(x+i\pi\right)^{1+x}+\left(x-i\pi\right)^{1+x}$ for $x>0$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I know according to Wolfram Alpha that, for all $x>0$, the following expression is real : $\left(x+i\pi\right)^{1+x}+\left(x-i\pi\right)^{1+x}$

Can anyone help me find the simplified form ?
This would net me a closed form for the integral I asked in the following post : [Closed form of $I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}{t^\kappa e^{-\ \frac{t}{\lambda}}\sin^2{\left(\frac{\pi t}{2\kappa\lambda}\right)}dt}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3904772/closed-form-of-i-int-0-inftyt-kappa-e-fract-lambda-sin2)

Comment: To see that it is real, you only have to check that this number is equal to mits conjugate (which is trivial).

Comment: You're absolutely right, but unfortunately I'm an actuary student (I focus on probability and stats) and it's been a long time since I handled complex numbers... plus I think the expression simplifies to a trigonometric form, and I reaaaally suck at those :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That the expression $$f(x) = (x+i\pi)^{1+x} + (x-i\pi)^{1+x}, \quad x > 0$$ has zero imaginary component is immediately appreciable by noting that the arguments of $x+i\pi$ and $x-i\pi$ are equal in magnitude and opposite in sign, thus by De Moivre's theorem, the arguments of $(x+i\pi)^{1+x}$ and $(x-i\pi)^{1+x}$ are also equal in magnitude and opposite in sign.  Their sum therefore has argument $0$.

To find a closed form, we can let $\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac{\pi}{x}$ and $r = \sqrt{x^2+\pi^2}$, hence $$x \pm i \pi = re^{\pm i\theta},$$ and $$(x\pm i \pi)^{1+x} = r^{1+x} e^{\pm (1+x) i \theta},$$ and $$f(x) = r^{1+x} (e^{(1+x)i \theta} + e^{-(1+x)i\theta}) = 2r^{1+x} \cos\left( (1+x) \theta \right) \\ = 2(x^2 + \pi^2)^{(1+x)/2} \cos \left( (1+x) \tan^{-1} \frac{\pi}{x} \right).$$

Comment: @TitoEliatron I prematurely finished my answer, which I have since edited.

Comment: THANK YOU !!! I will now answer the other post I had linked to...

Comment: To see it is real, it is simpler to check that $$\overline{f(x)}=\overline{(x+i\pi)^{1+x}+(x-i\pi)^{1+x}} = (x-i\pi)^{1+x}+(x+i\pi)^{1+x}=f(x).$$
Moreover, following yor answer, $f(x)=2\Re(x\pm i\pi)=r\cos\theta$, where $r=\sqrt{x^2+\pi^2}$ and $\theta=(1+x)\arctan(\pi/x)$.(@heropup check, you have a small mistake in $r$).